# What is D3js version support policy?

Tags: d3.js, version-control, backwards-compatibility

I'm new to `D3js` and before getting started **I want to understand how versions for the core and plugins are managed** so I don't find myself stuck with an old unsupported versions or using something that's too experimental.

If I look at the release history I see that `v4` was introduced back in `Jun 2016` (https://github.com/d3/d3/releases?after=v4.1.0) and `v5` in `Jan 2018` (https://github.com/d3/d3/releases?after=v5.0.1).

Yet, when I look at `D3js` code on the gallery (https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery), I see that most of it is based on `v3` which is `2` major releases behind.

For instance if I take a [Sankey example updated in May 2018](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/c9b90689c1438f57d649) it's still based on `v3`, and if I try to replace it with `v5` it breaks.

Another example: [someone had an issue with `v4` back in Feb 2017](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/1850), and the answer at the time and in April 2017 it was still not working (despite [it was already `v4.8` at the time](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases?after=v4.9.0),  nearly 1 year after the release of `v4`) :

[image]

So it seems that `v4/v5` are completely different branches from `v3` and are not even backwards compatible.

Hence my questions:

- To what extent is `v5` backward compatible with `v3`?
- How long will `v3` still be supported?

Comment: Most of the examples in that gallery were made by Mike Bostock, D3 creator. He once said that he planned to (slowly) converting most of the examples to v4 (or now v5), but obviously that's a lot of work: we can assume that, he being very busy, some of the examples will never be converted to v4/v5. However, anyone can fork those examples and convert them.

Comment: Regarding your first question, v5 is not compatible with v3, several changes are necessary. Of course it depends on the methods, chances are low but you can stumble upon a v3 code that works perfectly with v5 (as long as that hypothetic code doesn't use scales, axes, arcs, curves, hierarchies, force layouts, paths, etc...).

Comment: Related: [*"How long will D3.js v3 be supported?"*](/q/38923508).

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. So if I start fresh from now I should pick `v5` correct? (I just need to bear in mind that most examples would need to be adapted to that version)

Comment: Version 4 broke a substantial amount of API, but that is most of the time not that hard to convert v3 code to v4 code. I highly advice you to use v5, the updates are for the good, plus it will make your code easier to maintain when the API evolves.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/23257

Comment: Exactly, I second what @PierreCapo said: if you are staring to learn it, why not start using the last version? The advantages are several and the drawbacks very few (for instance, v5 won't work in Internet Explorer, because of Promises/Fetch... if you really care for IE, just use polyfills).

Comment: The only small problem I had in converting v3 examples was the porting of `d3.schemeCategory20[bc]` but that was easy to reimplement the same way as it is now done for `d3.schemeCategory10` by having a look at v3 source for the colour values and converting them to there hex equivalent. I have added a snippet as an Answer (comment is too short).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consolidating comments as 1 comprehensive answer:

**General philosophy**
It seems, and it's understandable given the fact that D3 creator is [creating/maintaining the library mostly by himself](https://github.com/d3/d3/graphs/contributors), that there isn't enough resources to design with backwards-compatibility nor maintain old code.

**Which version to choose**
Given the above, when starting fresh, it seems picking the latest version is the most sensible choice.

**Backward compatibility**
There have been backward incompatible changes going from `v3` to to `v5` ([v5](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases?after=v5.0.1) removed `d3-queue`, `d3-request`, `schemeCategory20`...). So it wouldn't be a shocker if in the future other backward incompatible changes are introduced.

**Legacy support**
It seems the moment a new version is released, support for the older version is abandoned and all efforts are focused on the new version:
https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/764274097995907072

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The D3v3 `schemeCategory20[bc]` are not available in v4(??) and v5.

Using the color numbers from the v3 source code and converting them to the hex equivalents we can use if in v5 like

```
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);
```

The small snippet

```
function d3_rgbHexString(value) { return "#" + (0x1000000 + value).toString(16).substring(1); }
d3.schemeCategory20  = [ 2062260, 11454440, 16744206, 16759672, 2924588, 10018698, 14034728, 16750742, 9725885, 12955861, 9197131, 12885140, 14907330, 16234194, 8355711, 13092807, 12369186, 14408589, 1556175, 10410725 ].map(d3_rgbHexString);
d3.schemeCategory20b = [ 3750777, 5395619, 7040719, 10264286, 6519097, 9216594, 11915115, 13556636, 9202993, 12426809, 15186514, 15190932, 8666169, 11356490, 14049643, 15177372, 8077683, 10834324, 13528509, 14589654 ].map(d3_rgbHexString);
d3.schemeCategory20c = [ 3244733, 7057110, 10406625, 13032431, 15095053, 16616764, 16625259, 16634018, 3253076, 7652470, 10607003, 13101504, 7695281, 10394312, 12369372, 14342891, 6513507, 9868950, 12434877, 14277081 ].map(d3_rgbHexString);
```

Comment: Thanks `rioV8` but I was asking about the general support policy, and details about the specific case of `schemeCategory20b`

Comment: The d3v3 examples I want to use I convert them to d3v5, not a lot of work, so there is no need to do new stuff in d3v3. The only thing missing was the `schemeCategory20` color sets. I just found that d3v4 has `schemeCategory20`. Maybe I will look into how that was implemented.